# how to obtain the value from an xml tag using FirstCHildElement

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I am working in C++. I would like to ask how to obtain the value text from:

```
<message> text </message>
```

I have

```
TiXmlHandle handle(&doc);
TiXmlElement* section;
section=doc.FirstChildElement("message");
```

How to do it from now on? I know I have to work with `.Element()` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `GetText()` to obtain the contents of `<message>`. I put your XML-contents in a file called `dummy.xml` and used the following code to print the contents:

```
TiXmlDocument doc("dummy.xml");

if(doc.LoadFile())
{
    TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
    TiXmlElement *pRoot;
    pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("message");
    printf("pRoot text: %s", pRoot->GetText());

}
```